# ClassCastException in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, listview

I have a little problem. I want to create navigation drawer with titles, but eclipse throws me a class cast exception. The problem is in adapter, but I can't find it. Can you please help me.
Here is code for my adapter

```
public class NavDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavDrawerItem>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, NavDrawerItem[] objects ) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null ;
    NavDrawerItem menuItem = this.getItem(position);
    if ( menuItem.getType() == NavMenuItem.ITEM_TYPE ) {
        view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem );
    }
    else {
        view = getSectionView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    }
    return view ;
}

public View getItemView( View convertView, ViewGroup parentView, NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem ) {

    NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem ;
    NavMenuItemHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.navdrawer_item, parentView, false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById( R.id.navmenuitem_label );
        ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navmenuitem_icon);

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuItemHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView ;
        navMenuItemHolder.image = i;

        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if ( navMenuItemHolder == null ) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuItem.getLabel().toString());

    return convertView ;
}

public View getSectionView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavMenuSection menuSection = (NavMenuSection) navDrawerItem ;
    NavMenuSectionHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.navdrawer_section, parentView, false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById( R.id.navmenusection_label );

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuSectionHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView ;
        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if ( navMenuItemHolder == null ) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuSectionHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuSection.getLabel().toString());

    return convertView ;
}

private static class NavMenuItemHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
    private ImageView image;
}

private static class NavMenuSectionHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
}

}
```

and here is code for my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavDrawerAdapter adapter;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ImageView menu;
private RelativeLayout rightRL;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    rightRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.whatYouWantInRightDrawerProfil);

    NavDrawerItem[] m = new NavDrawerItem[]{
            NavMenuSection.create(100, "Demos"),
            NavMenuItem.create(101, "kako si", false, this),
            NavMenuSection.create(200, "General"),
            NavMenuItem.create(202, "Rate this app", false, this)
    };
    adapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.navdrawer_item, m);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void onRight(View view) {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(rightRL);
}

}
```

This is my logcat from eclipse

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter$NavMenuSectionHolder cannot be cast to com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter$NavMenuItemHolder
>       at com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter.getItemView(NavDrawerAdapter.java:52)
>       at com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter.getView(NavDrawerAdapter.java:25)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2449)
>       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
>       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:866)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2385)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1979)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1222)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I just needed to add

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return this.getItem(position).getType();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isEnabled();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your issue is related to the fact that you get only one null `convertView`, so the tag content is set just once for `NavMenuSectionHolder` or `NavMenuItemHolder`. Usually, when you have to handle more than one convertView you can override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`. In your case, the two holder classes differ just for `ImageView`. So I would suggest you to have just one holder class, (inflating one layout), and hiding the `ImageView` when you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

you trying to cast navDrawerItem to navMenuItem

```
NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem;
```

change it with

```
NavDrawerItem drawerItem = (NavDrawerItem ) navDrawerItem;
```

and do accordingly..

Comment: so i have to change it also in getSectionView(). Insted NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem;

Comment: but that's wrong. The stacktrace says `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter$NavMenuSectionHolder cannot be cast to com.markoKurt.zeljko.NavDrawerAdapter$NavMenuItemHolder`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the logic for different layout like this,
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html

Answer (score 0):

In getItemView and getSectionView you can get different views, so you need to check class instance.

```
public View getSectionView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

NavMenuSection menuSection;
if (navDrawerItem !=null)
if (navDrawerItem instanceof NavMenuSection){
menuSection = navDrawerItem}
else {
menuSection = new NavMenuSection()
}else {
menuSection = new NavMenuSection()
}
public View getItemView( View convertView, ViewGroup parentView, NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem ) {

NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem ;
    NavMenuItemHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;
NavMenuSection menuSection;
if (menuItem!=null)
if (menuItem instanceof  NavMenuItem){
menuItem =  NavMenuItem
else {
menuItem = new  NavMenuItem()
}else {
menuItem= new  NavMenuItem()
}
```